# Win32api SetConsoleCtrlHandler runs when it should not

Tags: python, winapi

I'm trying to implement SetConsoleCtrlHandler from win32api in my Python script to execute a function when I close my script by clicking on the 'X' button on Windows cmd.

My issue is the print_test() runs after login causing open_latest_thread() not to run, instead of running print_test() only on unexpected exit. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
def print_test():
    print("test")

login()
win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(print_test(), True)
while True:
    try:
        open_latest_thread()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that the [`HandlerRoutine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) is not defined correctly. It has a [`DWORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine) type input parameter and `BOOL` type return value. Like this:

```
def print_test(ctrlType):
    print("test")
    return false
```

And use `print_test` instead of `print_test()` as parameter when you call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. Like this:

```
win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(print_test, True)
```

For `DWORD` you can refer to `ctypes.wintypes.DWORD`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is my code and it doesn't seem to close the selenium browser on exit.

https://pastebin.com/94vhKTzA

Comment: @Foong Has the initial question about function executed sequence solved? If yes, so this line `browser.close()` is executed. However, why `browser.close()` doesn't close the browser is another different topic.